# Serializing maps which are initialized in constructors

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

I've just encountered an interesting problem related to Java serialization.

It seems that if my map is defined like this:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
  put("param1", "value1");
  put("param2", "value2");
}};
```

And I try to serialize it to a file with ObjectOutputStream:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
oos.writeObject(params);
```

...I get java.io.NotSerializableException.

However, if instead I put values to the map the standard way:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("param1", "value1");
params.put("param2", "value2");
```

...then serialization work fine.

Can anybody tell me why it happens and what's the difference between these statements? I think they should work the same, but apparently I'm missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first example is creating an anonymous inner class. How ?

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>() {};
```

would create a new class derived from `HashMap` (note the following braces, in which you can put methods, members etc.)

Your map initialisation then declares an initialiser block thus:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>() { 
                                                             { // here } 
                                                           };
```

and in that you call your population methods.

This idiom is fine, *but you have to be aware that you're creating a new class*, not just a new object.

Because this class is an inner class, it'll have an implicit `this` pointer to the containing outer class. Your anonymous class would be serialisable due to its derivation from a serialisable class. However your outer class (referenced by the `this` pointer) isn't.

Tools like `XStream`, which serialise to XML via reflection, will discover the `this` pointer and attempt to serialise the surrounding object, which is similarly confusing.

Comment: By `static initialiser`, you mean `instance initializer`?

Comment: so what would be the expected enclosing class?

Comment: @Shark - I simply mean the class containing the above definition of the derived HashMap

Comment: oh, so suppose if it's instantiated in a MainApp class, we'd get a java.io.NotSerializableException because MainApp doesn't implement Serializable as well? interesting.

Comment: so how he can do it serialisable  although he created an inner class ?

Comment: @Shark - that would be the case. If it was serialisable then your serialisation would succeed but you'd serialise a lot more than you intended

Comment: @URL87. I perhaps a) wouldn't create a serialisable class b) override the serialisation behaviour. In this scenario I think a) is preferable

Comment: thats exactly what i thought... i remember when this (or something really similar) kicked me in the balls in college and i had NO clue why i had to implement Serializable and end up with all the extra serialization :D

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to supplement @Brian Agnew's answer with this suggestion:

I had a case where I needed slightly different behavior out of an object, so I extended its capabilities with an anonymous inner class as you did in the example.  The outer class was a GUI application, and I did not make it serializable because that just wasn't necessary, so therefore like @Brian said, no anonymous inner classes could be serializable, even if the classes they were extending were.

In this situation, you simply have to define different behavior for when a class is deserialized and when it is again serialized.  If you have a class with a specific constructor, use a method like this in your class:

```
public FunctionalObject getNewFunctionalObject (String param1, String param2) {
    // Use an anonymous inner class to extend the behavior
    return new FunctionalObject (param1, param2) {
        { 
            // Initialization block code here
        }
        // Extended behavior goes here
    };
}
```

So when you are deserializing, you can make a call like this:

```
FunctionalObject fo = (FunctionalObject) objectInputStream.readObject ();
fo = getNewFunctionalObject(fo.getParam1(), fo.getParam2());
```

When serializing, you will need to create a `new` object that is a clone of the old object.  Some classes have this behavior built in, and in others you will have to specifically define it.  For serialization, if you have a constructor that can clone it, or if your class has the `clone` method defined, you could do this:

```
objectOutputStream.writeObject ( fo.clone() );
```

Then, the `clone` of that object will no longer be a reference to your anonymous inner class, but a reference to an actual copy of the object, which is serializable.

In your example's case, you could have just done this:

```
// Assuming objectOutputStream has already been defined
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("param1", "value1");
    put("param2", "value2");
}};
objectOutputStream.writeObject (new HashMap<String,String> (params));
```

This works because the `HashMap` class has a constructor that will return a clone of whatever `HashMap` is passed into it.  That was a lot of words to say something simple, but I wished I would have had this advice sooner myself.